# How to exclude the output file from ls output

Tags: io-redirection, ls

Let's say I have these files on desktop:

```
aaa.jpg  
bbb.jpg
```

I want to list these two jpg's and output them to a .txt file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Desktop
ls -1 > all.txt
```

With this code the `all.txt` would have the following:

```
aaa.jpg  
bbb.jpg  
all.txt
```

I just want the two jpg's in `all.txt`.

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/117549

Answer (score 3):

you can have the ls filter for only .jpg files

```
ls *.jpg > all.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

A more general solution than the one proposed by @ShayneManning:

```
ls | grep -v '^all.txt$' > all.txt
```

`grep` is used to filter lines by content. The option `-v` inverses the filter. So, `all.txt` will be excluded from the output of `ls`. All the other names will be printed to `all.txt`.

Comment: and will also exclude a file named, for example, "almostall.txt"

Comment: @JeffSchaller indeed... fixed!

Answer (score 2):

thanks for the response, but I wanted to list everything, not just the .jpg. I realized there is a simple solution to that which is

```
ls * > all.txt
```

instead of

```
ls > all.txt
```

Does anyone know why adding the wildcard would prevent the output file to include itself?

Comment: This is because the star is expanded to the list of all the entries in the current directory by the shell, before the command is issued. You should post this as a new question for details. Note also that your command has a different behaviour. If there are subdirectories in your directory, their content will be listed too.

Comment: If you have subdirectories and don't want to expand them, you can do `ls -d * > all.txt`